# XSLT replace remove html tags

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt

Why is the function `replace()` removing html tags of my variable?

I have two variables:

```
    <xsl:variable name="content1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="my-mode">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="content2">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$content1, 'a', 'b')" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

`$content1` has html tags, `$content2` hasn't, why?

Comment: `replace` is a string function, that expects a string as the first parameter. If you pass in a node as the first parameter it will get the string value of that node and use that. So, for example, the string value of `<content><a>hello</a> <b>world</b></content>` is simply "hello world", and so that is what `replace` will act on.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is defined to operate on a string, and you pass it a node, then it "atomizes" the node (extracts its content) to create the string that the function requires. This removes other information about the node, such as its name. (Note that the tags themselves were removed earlier, when the source document was parsed into a node tree.)

I guess you probably intended to write

```
<xsl:variable name="content2">
    <xsl:copy-of select="replace($content1, 'a', 'b')" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Note that this would be better written as

```
<xsl:variable name="content2" select="replace($content1, 'a', 'b')"/>
```

to avoid the cost of repeated conversions from strings to text nodes and then back to strings.

Without knowing exactly what's is your source document it's difficult to advise exactly how you should be writing this code. If $content is an element with simple text content and no attributes, then the simplest is probably

```
<xsl:variable name="content2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$content1" mode="replace"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="replace">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'a', 'b')" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. `content1` is actually a HTML node and I want to print it into a javascript variable (e.g. `var myContent = '<xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'a', 'b')" />';`). I need also to do some text replacement, not only on the text but also on attributes of the HTML.